# Can someone please tell me what kind of frame this is

Tags: identify-this-bike, build

Can someone please tell me what kind of frame this is. Thanks[image: bike frame]

Comment: Bog-standard BMX, probably Chinese.

Comment: What practical problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

It is a likely steel frame, painted in faded yellow paint.  No decals suggest its been repainted or stripped for some reason.  The cranks are painted too suggests a repaint or a low cost bike.

The BB is a ashtabula. Pedals look to be possibly a 1/2 pedal thread.  Headset is threaded.  There are rear brake mounts visible, but brakes are missing.  I don't see any front brake either, they would have been single-pivot calipers based on the one hole.

The pedals appear to be regular flats of a budget plastic construction.  If they don't spin freely you will need to strip and clean the bearings+races on the inside.

You'll need a lot more parts before its rideable.  Wheels tubes tyres, brake calipers cables and levers, bars and stem, grips, seat seatpost and pinch bolt.

The chain may not be savable, a replacement would be advisable.

The dirt implies its been in the ground for a while, which may be good or bad.  Need to look all over for rust, and remove/treat whatever has formed already.

Now what's your goal for your BMX ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the original T-1 TerribleOne frames.
However the 1 piece cranks and threaded headset with press-in loose bearing cups suggest it is much more inexpensive frame destined for the trash.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a GT to me.   Comp or a mach 2

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This would be a much better answer if you were to include photos of the bikes you are suggesting, showing how they are similar.